# Zebra RW420 factory reset

Tags: zebra-printers

I need to know how to perform a hard reset (factory defaults) to a RW420 Zebra wireless 
printer.

I read all the guides but it seems that this function is non implemented.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Zebra website the RW420 supports ZPL. So you can use the a listing from the [ZPL manual](http://www.zebra.com/id/zebra/na/en/documentlibrary/manuals/en/zpl_ii_programming2.html&ei=1NG7T83tD4KY8gTty73ACg&usg=AFQjCNHQub1MBc4D-wKXN3kXwbw4vSPC3A&sig2=ft0ttL5tr-oJmRKvJmH1dA) for "Configuration Update", the ^JU command, to reload factory settings. You can reload the factory settings by sending the following to the printer.

```
^XA
^JUF
^JUN
^JUS
^XZ
```

Comment: Well, a long time has passed from last time I've been here. The escape sequence has not did the magic trick. But, actually, the problem was that I was not able to see the usual menu that you can see on the printer's LCD display. I asked to Zebra support and they suggested to upload several files (token from another Zebra RW420 printer) to the printer with this kind of issue. This time, after a reboot, the printer has been able to show again the menu and so on.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use Zebra Setup Utilities.

- First you need to connect to your printer.
- After this you can go to printer-tools and there you will find the factory-reset option.